# After I did update to Xcode 14.3.1 every time I add a new File.swift it cannot be found on the scope

Tags: xcode

[image]

I've tried to delete the file and target to the right folders but it seems not working.

I also open old projects that were build with Xcode 14.3 and it was working properly, but when I also try to add new files in those project same error was showing!

Comment: maybe configuration problems arised. does this happen for new projects as well ? maybe you should report it here https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: yeah it does even with new projects!!